# Field rendered invisible when code block enabled

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I have this weird issue when altering a webform. Below are two versions of my code:

```
function tubitekuz_form_webform_client_form_97_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['submitted']['kullanici_adi'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'event' => 'blur',
      'callback' => '_tubitekuz_do_stuff',
    ),
  );
}
```

The above code renders my field invisible, while

```
function tubitekuz_form_webform_client_form_97_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 $form['submitted']['kullanici_adi']['#ajax'] = array(
    'event' => 'blur',
    'callback' => '_tubitekuz_do_stuff',
  );
}
```

gives me [image: this screen].

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why. It seems our designer chose to add `display:none` to `ajax-processed` class, which is added to `#ajax` calls.